# Splitting a list of strings based on specific words

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains paths to specific files such as

```
path_list =['Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/0',
          'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/1',
          'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/2',
          'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/1',
          'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/2',
          'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/0',
          'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/1',
          'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/2',<------ Last time dog_00239 appears #first break point
          'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/3',
          'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/0',
          'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/1',
          'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/2',
          'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/141/view/full/0',
          'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/141/view/full/1',<------ Last time dog_00241 appears #Second breakpoint
          'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/3',
          'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/4',
          'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/0',
          'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/1',]
```

What I would like to do is split this list into 3 new smaller lists.

First list would be from start till first breakpoint

```
Fisrt_list = ['Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/0',
         'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/1',
         'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/2',
         'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/1',
         'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/2',
         'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/0',
         'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/1',
         'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/2',]<------ Last time dog_00239 appears #first break point
```

Second list would be right after the first break point till second breakpoint

```
second_list = ['Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/3',
     'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/0',
     'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/1',
     'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/2',
     'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/141/view/full/0',
     'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/141/view/full/1',]<------ Last time dog_00241 appears #Second breakpoint
```

And third list would be right after the second break point till the end

```
third_list = ['Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/3',
     'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/4',
     'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/0',
     'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/1',]
```

What I have tried to so far is, I created a for loop and break it when an if condition is met and see what I get such as:

```
new_paths = []
fisrt_breakpoint = 'dog_00239'

for i in range (len(path_list)):
new_paths.append(path_list[i])
   if fisrt_breakpoint in path_list:
    break
```

This does split the list and keeps a smaller part of it but what it keeps in new_paths are the elements after the breakpoint I set and not the elements up to this breakpoint. But also I am nowhere putting the condition, because I don't know how to do it, to use as a breakpoint the last time this word appears in this list, because I am assuming even if the above code worked it would split it the first time it saw the word "dog_00239".

Also I tried :

```
new_paths = [x for x in path_list if first_breakpoint in x]
```

But this gets all the items that contain "dog_00239" while what I want to do is get everything up to this point.

Thank you in advance for your time,
I'd really appreaciate any help, sorry for any any mistakes or if I am not very clear with my question as I am new in here and in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`

```py
import itertools
import re

# this is the function you define ranges
def get_breakpoint_id(x):
    if(x <= 239): # i.e. /dog_00239
        return 0
    elif(239 < x <= 241): # i.e. /dog_00240 to /dog_00241
        return 1
    else:
        return 2


[list(g) for _,g in itertools.groupby(path_list, key=lambda x: get_breakpoint_id(int(re.findall(r'dog_(\d+)/', x)[0])))]
```

```
[['Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/0',
  'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/1',
  'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/2',
  'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/1',
  'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/2',
  'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/0',
  'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/1',
  'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/2'],
 ['Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/3',
  'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/0',
  'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/1',
  'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/2',
  'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/141/view/full/0',
  'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/141/view/full/1'],
 ['Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/3',
  'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/4',
  'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/0',
  'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/1']]
```

Comment: Just tried your solution and it does work exactly as expected but I haven't worked at all with itertools.groupby so i would like to ask you some questions. First where are the new lists stored how could I access them and perform other operations on them afterwards? And also at..(int(re.findall(r'dog_(\d+)/', x)[0])))] how does this work after the _(\d+)/', cause up to this point I understand it but the ,x ?. Thank you again

Comment: you can store the output in a new list `output = [list(g) for _,g in itertools.groupby(path_list, key=lambda x: get_breakpoint_id(int(re.findall(r'dog_(\d+)/', x)[0])))]`. Then you can use `output` list.

Comment: `(int(re.findall(r'dog_(\d+)/', x)[0])))` here actually `regular expression` is used to extracked the numver `dog_XXXX`. Then based on the extracted `XXXX`, the grouping is done.

Comment: You can read more about `itertools.groupby()` online. Basicall id there is a list `[1,1,1,2,2,1,1,4,4,4]` it can group it like `(1,1,1), (2,2), (1,1), (4,4,4)`

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative solution that doesn't involve importing packages, you can use a nested for-loop:

```py
breakpoints = ["dog_00240", "dog_00242"] 
path_list =['Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/0',
          'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/1',
          'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/2',
          'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/1',
          'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/2',
          'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/0',
          'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/1',
          'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/2',
          'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/3',
          'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/0',
          'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/1',
          'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/2',
          'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/141/view/full/0',
          'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/141/view/full/1',
          'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/3',
          'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/4',
          'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/0',
          'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/1',]
lists = []
new_list = []

for file_path in path_list:
    for point in breakpoints:
        # If point is a breakpoint, add new_list to lists
        if point in file_path:
            lists.append(new_list)
            new_list = []
            # Remove breakpoint
            breakpoints.remove(point)
            continue
    # Otherwise, add path to new_list
    new_list.append(file_path)
# Add final new_list to lists
lists.append(new_list)
        
first = lists[0]
second = lists[1]
third = lists[2]

print(first, second, third)
# Prints 
""" (['Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/0',  
 'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/1', 
'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/2', 
'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/1', 
'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/2', 
'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/0', 
'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/1', 
'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/2'], 
['Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/3', 
'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/0', 
'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/1', 
'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/982160/view/full/2', 
'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/141/view/full/0', 
'Animals/dog_00241/2D_rendering/141/view/full/1'], 
['Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/3', 
'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/4', 
'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/0', 
'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/1']) """
```

Note that I set the breakpoints to be the first path to break at, instead of the path at which to break once you've reached the last instance of it.

Comment: Just tried your proposed solution and it does work great, the breakpoints I have are the ending points overall start (0) and overall end (10000) and because I have thousands of such paths I am afraid there might be jumps and sometimes the next starting point might not be nessecerally numerically the next one ie. 239 next 240 but I could find the exact next starting point and follow your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and compact solution:

```
breakpoints_numbers = [0,239,241,999]
breakpoints_paths = [f'Animals/dog_00{b}' for b in breakpoints_numbers]
pathslist = [sublist for sublist in [[p for p in path_list if p>b[0] and p<=b[1]] for b in zip(breakpoints_paths[:-1],breakpoints_paths[1:])] if sublist != []]
```

In the first line you create a list of breakpoints, including 000 and 999.

In the second line they're transformed to paths, that can be used for comparinsons.

In the third line you have the list of lists you want, which are filtered exclusively at the lower bound and inclusively at the upper bound, which is what you were expecting.

Comment: I just tried you solution but the exact example that you proposed and gives that result

[['Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/0',
  'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/1',
  'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/131/view/full/2',
  'Animals/dog_00238/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/1',
  'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/906271/view/full/2',
  'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/3',
  'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/1881/view/full/4',
  'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/0',
  'Animals/dog_00242/2D_rendering/2487/view/full/1'],
 [],
 []]

Comment: So it creates a new list containing all the elements and two empty at the end

Comment: You are right, There were empty sublists left. I have updated the answer with cleanup to avoid them. The edition was adding `[sublist for sublist in __dirypathslistwithemptysublists__ if sublist != []]`

Comment: It removes not only the last empty ones, but also empty ones in the middle, once they seem fairly unnecessary - at least to me, I don't know to you.

Comment: Thank you for the update but `pathslist = [sublist for sublist in [[p for p in path_list if p>b[0] and p<=b[1]] for b in zip(breakpoints_paths[:-1],breakpoints_paths[1:]) if sublist != []]]` . I think there is a ] missing at the end and other than that I think you meant `sublist!= []` instead of  `sublist !+ []` .  But even with those changes it throws a `NameError: name 'sublist' is not defined`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. From the beginning the problem was in the second line `f'Animals/dog_00{b}'` (it was wrongly `f'Animals/dog_{b}'` without the zeros), and the cleanup wasn't necessary at all, but I leave it there. This time I have tested. Sorry for all the mistakes!

Comment: The whole point is that python is able do to comparisons with strings just like with numbers, on a char by char basis (compare first characters, then seconds, and so on). So, `'Animals/dog_00239/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/2'` <= `'Animals/dog_00239'` < `'Animals/dog_00240/2D_rendering/965947/view/full/3'`. (without the zeros, the breakpoints were always higher than the filenames)